# sql inner and left join + performance

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, join

I have 3 tables:

```
room
room location
room_storys
```

If anyone creates a room, everytime comes a row automaticlly to room location. room_storys table can be empty.

Now I want to inner join the tables.

If I make this I get no results:

```
SELECT
r.name, 
r.date, 

rl.city, 
rl.street, 
rl.number, 
rl.name,

rs.source,
rs.date

FROM room r

INNER JOIN room_location rl
ON rl.room_id = 67

INNER JOIN room_storys rs
ON rs.room_id = 67

LIMIT 1;
```

If I make this:

```
INNER JOIN room_storys rs
ON rs.room_id = 67
```

to this:

````
LEFT JOIN room_storys rs
ON rs.room_id = 67
```

then it works. But I heard that left join has no good performance, how you would perform this query above? Or is that okey?
````

Comment: Your JOIN's don't have a relation between the tables on the left and right. And did you create indexes on the columns involved? https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every `JOIN` type has its pros and cons but, for a query like yours, the “cost” is negligible. One recommendation would be to have the tables reference each other rather than a specific `id` as part of the `ON` clause. Specificity can be crucial with `OUTER JOIN`s in some situations. Your query can be written like this:

```
SELECT r.`name`, 
       r.`date`, 

       rl.`city`, 
       rl.`street`, 
       rl.`number`, 
       rl.`name`,

       rs.`source`,
       rs.`date`
  FROM `room` r INNER JOIN `room_location` rl ON r.`id` = rl.`room_id`
           LEFT OUTER JOIN `room_storys` rs ON rl.`room_id` = rs.`room_id`
 WHERE r.`id` = 67;
```

This change solves the problem of returning *everything* in `room`, which was mitigated by the `LIMIT 1`. It also ensures a record is returned even if there is nothing in `room_stories` for the `room_id`.

Hope this gives you something to think about with future queries

Comment: Not for MySQL they’re not. The question has MySQL tagged (in addition to PostgreSQL, I’ll grant), so MySQL is the format I went with 

Comment: Then you should use standard SQL syntax. Simply omit the backticks, since there is no need to quote these identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way:

`ON` says how the tables are related, such as

```
 ON room.id = room_story.room_id
```

`WHERE` is used for filtering, such as

```
 WHERE room.id = 67
```

Also, `JOIN` (or `INNER JOIN` requires the matching rows in each of the 2 tables to both exist.  `LEFT JOIN` says that the matching row in the *right* table is optionally missing.

Putting those together, I think this is what you needed:

```
FROM room r
INNER JOIN room_location rl  ON rl.room_id = r.id
INNER JOIN room_storys rs    ON rs.room_id = r.id
WHERE r.id = 67
```

This becomes irrelevent (I think):  `LIMIT 1`